# How to launch a huge number of processes in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a.out lot of times from command line, but am not able to start the processes in background because bash treats it as a syntax error.

```
for f in `seq 20`; do ./a.out&; done //incorrect syntax for bash near '&'
```

How can I place & on command line so that bash doesn't complain, and I am allowed to 
run these processes in background, so that I can generate load on the system.

P.S: I don't want to break it into multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
for f in `seq 20`; do ./a.out& done
```

`&` terminates a command just like `;` or `&&`, `||`, `|`.

This means that bash expects a command between `&` and `;` but can't find one. Hence the error.

Comment: Yikes - yet another reason to love zsh... ;-).  Great job spotting that... though I guess once bitten it'd be hard to forget.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a command terminator as well as `;` ; do not use both.

And use bash syntax instead of using seq, which is not available on all Unix systems.

```
for f in {1..20} ; do ./a.out& done
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` after `a.out`:

```
for f in `seq 20`; do ./a.out& done
```

Answer (score 0):

Break that into multiple lines or remove the ; after the &